# WPF Window MinWidth depending on size of toolbar

Tags: wpf, binding, window, width, stackpanel

Before asking this question I have looked at all related questions, but have not found anything relevant.

In my application I have toolbox style bar, which is basically stack panel with bunch of buttons. User may change which buttons are shown in toolbar.

Window width may be changed, but it can not be smaller then width of toolbar.

At first I was hoping to bind the `MinWidth` property to the `StackPanel` `Width` property and create converter that adds few pixels to `Width` of the `StackPanel`. The problem is that my converter does not get Width of `StackPanel`, just NaN as value :(

Unfortunately, `StackPanel` width is set to `Auto` and I can not change that.

Is there any way I can make my Window `MinWidth` dependable on `Width` of `StackPanel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ActualWidth`, not `Width`.

Width is the requested width, or NaN for "Auto", `ActualWidth` is the, well, actual width after all the layout is calculated.

Comment: That's great!  I've been wanting to know how to do this myself.

Comment: Thank You for you answer!

I've tried using ActualWidth, but it creates another problem

Please have a loot at this screen shot

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/204110/actualwidth.PNG

This solution won't let me make Window's width smaller, it only allows me to increase Width

Comment: Explicitly set HorizontalAlignment to left, works like charm...Thank You.